# Where should I place a doorstop so it gets hit by the door with the least amount of force?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

[image: door and doorstops]

I was wondering if placing a doorstop the furthest away from the hinge means it will get hit with the most amount of force (position 3) when I swing the door open.

If that's true (and I want to prevent the doorstop from getting unglued from the floor), wouldn't position 1 mean it would receive less of a hit (since the lever arm is smaller)?

Surprisingly, when I looked online, they recommend using a [position closer to 2](https://itprospt.com/qa/67095/d-l-why-are-door-stops-there-6-pt-a-well-designed), because it's better for the hinges (but I don't understand what they mean by horizontal force).

So, assuming hinges are not an issue, would position 1 receive the least amount of force?

Comment: "Give me a lever (with a long arm) and I'll move the world"

Answer (score 0):

I would say position 3 receive the least amount of force. Because it has the longest arm, to generate the same amount of torque it needs the least amount of force.